# RSS Feed filtering tool?

Tags: rss, feed

I'm looking for a tool which could filter (based upon the keywords specified) not only the description + title of the feed item, but could also follow the specified link in feed and should consider its content for matching too. Anyone knows if there's an existing tool for that or do I have to program it myself?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should give you enough options:
http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/6_ways_to_filter_your_rss_feeds.php

Comment: Yes exactly... just edited the title now.

Comment: Just found that, it should give you enough options: http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/6_ways_to_filter_your_rss_feeds.php

Comment: Thanks, Yahoo Pipes has a block called 'Web Services API' which can be extended to customize my needs.